# Acces mass of part in a macro from Catia

Tags: macros, catia

I created a macro which calls the properties of my part with this code: 
ReferenceProduct.PartNumer
ReferenceProduct.Revision

Now I need to call the Mass of the part. Which Code could I use? Maybe something like ReferenceMass.Mass... ReferenceProduct.Mass.. ?? I can´t find the code that will work.

In advance, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the mass from the inertia:

```
Dim objInertia    As Inertia
Dim objProd       As Product

Set objProd = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Product
Set objInertia = objProd.ReferenceProduct.GetTechnologicalObject("Inertia")
MsgBox objInertia.Mass
```

Function `GetTechnologicalObject("Inertia")` can crash easily if the object is not correctly defined, like if the product has no material defined. To prevent this, wrap it in a nice function.