# Catia Vba How can I find mass of a Product

Tags: vba, catia

On Catia Vba, I want to find mass of a product. Is there any function for the finding mass?

I choose the product after when I run the macro, the result should show me an a message box about mass of the product. Just it how can I learn.

Comment: You could use the inertia object like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29741939/acces-mass-of-part-in-a-macro-from-catia) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48554707/catscript-the-method-findobject-failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one method among many others. It all depends on what weight you're really looking for.

```
    Sub CATMain()
    
    Dim productDocument As productDocument
    Dim product As product
    
    Set productDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument
    Set product = productDocument.product
    
    MsgBox product.Analyze.Mass & " Kg"
    
    End Sub
```